# Data parsing and string index out of range error

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

I am new to programming and I just started learning data parsing.
I wrote a program to search and print words starting with the input alphabet, parsing data from a `.txt` file but it is only displaying correct result with alphabets `a-g`, and

`IndexError:string index out of range` with any other alphabet.

The following is from python(3.5.1) and the link to list of words https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mohdomama/Scrabble-C/master/Dict.txt

```
def main():
    #read file
    file = open("dict.txt","r")
    lines = file.readlines()
    file.close()
    word = input("Choose the alphabet")
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        if line[0] == word:
           print(line)

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get it a bit wrong. `readlines()` reads in the whole file at once and splits it by line, and returns list of **lines**. Then iterating over it returns **string objects**.

So for example, reading your file can be equal to something like f:

```
f = ['first line', 'two line', 'third line']
for line in f:
    print line  # 'first line' (string)
```

so comparing line[0] is the same as doing 'first line'[0] = 'f'

If you want to compare words, you need to split the line into words. You can do
that by:

```
for line in f:
    words = line.split()  # ['first', 'line']
    words[0] == word:
        print word
```

Answer (score -1):

When you see an `IndexError` for a given object, check the existence / "truthyness" of the object first. Empty lists, Empty strings, etc. are not Truthy.

So instead of :

`if line[0] == word:`

Try:

`if line and line[0] == word:`

When the first check fails ( `if line` ), it will not continue to check the index ( `line[0]` ) since Python's `and` statement requires that BOTH conditions be `True`.

Comment: It works and does the first "line" in "if line and line[0]==word:" checks its existence?

Comment: What does "Python's `and`" mean? It is just [boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra)

Comment: @OmairKhan yes `if line` checks if `line` exists and is truthy. @RedEyed - I just mean the use of `and` in the Python language, obviously.

Comment: your answer is incorrect, it won't solve the problem. the question has problem in it's logic